# How could I validate/compare two dates in node js to ensure endDate is withing after 24hours of startDate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

I have two dates i.e. `startDate = 2018-11-14T08:55:03.021Z` and `endDate = 2018-11-14T09:13:03.097Z`. How can I compare this two dates to ensure the `endDate` is within 24 hours after startDate. I want to add more validation like `endDate` should not be greater than `currentDate`. How could I do this? Is there any algorithm available?

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if you use some library to handle dates. I prefer using moment library for date related operations in JavaScript https://momentjs.com/docs/. You can use the code below to get the difference in hours using moment.

```
let momentStartDate = moment(startdate);
let momentEndDate = moment(endDate);
let duration = moment.duration(momentEndDate.diff(momentStartDate));
let differenceInHours = duration.asHours();
console.log(differenceInHours)
```